# linkbutton oncommand issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asplinkbutton, datalistitem, commandargument

I am using 2 linkbuttons inside seperate dataitem server controls on my asp.net web page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Item1" runat="server"  CommandName="first"  
      OnCommand="Item1_Onclick" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %`>"  
      Text="<%# Container.DataItem %`>" >    
</asp:LinkButton`>
```

and

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Item2" runat="server"  CommandName="second"  
      OnCommand="Item2_Onclick" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %`>"  
      Text="<%# Container.DataItem %`>" >    
</asp:LinkButton`>
```

When I extract the command name inside c# as

```
e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim();
```

it does give me the correct the name however the command arugument

```
e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim();
```

for item2 is not what I expect. It is NOT that of item1, but the one that I set initially as datasource for the datalist control of item2. It does not give me the latest dataitem string value that I am expecting out of item2 linkbutton. What can be the problem? Where am I wrong?

Also, the event for item2 is fired ONLY for the first time and not after that? Is there some silly mistake that I am doing?

Comment: I would guess that the second link button is pasted in the wrong place :)

Comment: they are pasted in 2 seperate datalist control within the itemtemplate tags. item1 inside datalist1 tag and item2 inside datalist2 tag. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem. I had not included the if(!IsPostBack) as the first statement in my void Page_Load method !! That was stupid of me. Thanks anyways for all your time and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In the command argument you are not providing the property name in the data item

```
"<%# Container.DataItem.ProeprtyName %`>"
```

Say your datasource is a User object and you need the userid as the command argument it should be `<%# Container.DataItem.UserID%`>`